# javascript replace character with loop

Tags: javascript, loops, replace

This should be simple but I am not sure why it isn't working:

```
function kebabToSnake (str){
    var string = "";
    var chart = "";
    for(i=0; i < str.lenght; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) == "-") {
            chart = "_";
            string = string + chart;
        }
        else {
            chart = str.charAt(i);
            string = string + chart;
        }
    }
    return string
}
```

I know I could do it with str.replace(/-/g,"_") but I cannot see what's wrong with the above, besides being too long. Any help would be great.

Comment: example for input and output?

Comment: @basement got the answer. str.length not leght

Comment: What happens when you debug your code (eg, step through it line-by-line in the debugger)? What do you see?

Answer (score 3):

*You spelled "length" wrong.* ( on line 4 )

It works after the spelling correction.

```js
function kebabToSnake (str){
    var string = "";
    var chart = "";
    for(i=0; i < str.length; i++){  //fixed spelling from 'str.lenght'
        if (str.charAt(i) == "-") {
            chart = "_";
            string = string + chart;
        }
        else {
            chart = str.charAt(i);
            string = string + chart;
        }
    }
    return string
}

var body = document.querySelector( 'body' ),
    output = kebabToSnake( '-' ); //First test with '-' in conditional statement

body.innerHTML = output; //display to body

output = kebabToSnake( 'Another String' ); //Second test with random text triggering ELSE statement

body.innerHTML += '<br>' + output; //display to body
```

Comment: Lol I can't believe I didn't notice, it was driving me crazy. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this goal by using RegExp more concisely:

```
function kebabToSnake (str) {
    return str.replace(/-/g, '_');
}
```

Comment: ‘coz '-' is a special purpose character in RegExp, so it should be escaped when you use it as a plain character to match.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. But in practice, I always ask my programmers to escape it 'coz there's no negative effect on correctness.